# PHP: Recursively enhance array from set of strings

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that needs to be enhanced dynamically from the values of several strings.

```
$paths = array(
    '1/4/6',
    '1/2/4/12/4'
);

// desired result
$target = array(
    1 => array(
        2 => array(
            4 => array(
                12 => array(
                    4 => 'somevalue'
                )
            )
        ),
        4 => array(
            6 => 'somevalue'
        )
    )
);
```

Question is: how would I get from $paths to $target?

Thank you

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Please show us your efforts, don't just ask the community to solve the entire task for you.

Comment: It very easy using ```explode``` but you should try once from your side.

Comment: what if a next part starts with `2/4...` or `4/12...`?

Comment: @mitkosoft My impression is that the first number in the string always represents the top level.

Comment: So far I have not attempted anything except hammering my head.

Comment: Explode only creates a one-dimensional array. Of course explode would first seperate the strings (sorry, should have omitted that step).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explode on `/` for a path say `'1/4/6'`. Now, you have `1`,`4` and `6`. 
Keep assigning them iteratively to the previous parent key. In the below code, I have made use of `&` to edit the same address location of the child.

```
<?php

$paths = array(
    '1/4/6',
    '1/2/4/12/4'
);

$target = array();

foreach($paths as $path){
    $temp = &$target;
    foreach(explode("/",$path) as  $key){
        if(!isset($temp[$key])) $temp[$key] = array();
        $temp = &$temp[$key];
    }

    $temp = 'some value';
}


print_r($target);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/P3VQB

Comment: Spot on, thank you!